# Change of variable formula for Haar measure on product of Lie Groups

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, change-of-variable, geometric-measure-theory, haar-measure

**First let me recall the *usual* change of variable formula:**

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bijection which is Frechet differentiable, $U\in\mathrm{Open}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be given. Then the [change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) says that $$ \int_U f\circ\varphi = \int_{\varphi(U)}f\,\cdot|\det(D\left(\varphi^{-1}\right))| \tag{CoV}$$ where $D\left(\varphi^{-1}\right)$ is the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) of $\varphi^{-1}$.

**Now let me present the context I am *actually* interested in:**

Let now $G$ be a (matrix?) Lie group. Let us interpret $G^n$ as the Cartesian product (which is itself a Lie group I presume). Let $\varphi:G^n\to G^n$ be a given bijection, $U\in\mathrm{Open}(G^n)$ and $\mu$ be the Haar measure on $G$. If $f:G^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is given, then

**My question:**

What is the analog of (CoV) for my context? I.e., what is $$ \int_{(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in U} (f\circ\varphi)(g_1,\dots,g_n)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(g_1)\dots\mathrm{d}\mu(g_n) = ? $$